# SOAP response comparison/format

Tags: xml, soap, tags, format, response

I was hired to rewrite some web-service written in Java to .NET. Supposedly, the response needs to contain the same elements, (which it does, with my new response I'm getting back the right elements), but my question is about the tags. Do the tags need to be exactly the same as well? This web-service will be consumed by a third party company, so for now it is hard to test since the only version we have is in production. Here are both responses:

Original Response:

```
  <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <env:Header/>
<env:Body>
  <m:redCodeResponse xmlns:m="http://com/agentcorp/webservice/vax">
     <m:RedCodeResult>
        <java:AgencyID xmlns:java="java:com.agentcorp.ejb.webservices.vax">56693</java:AgencyID>
        <java:AgentID xmlns:java="java:com.agentcorp.ejb.webservices.vax">757803</java:AgentID>            
     </m:RedCodeResult>
  </m:redCodeResponse>
```

New Response:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<s:Header />
<s:Body>
<redCodeResponse xmlns="http://com/agentcorp/webservice/vax">
  <RedCodeResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/MyFirstWCFService" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <a:AgencyID>56693</a:AgencyID>
    <a:AgentID>757803</a:AgentID>        
  </RedCodeResult>
</redCodeResponse>
```

Comment: I would ask the third party company

Comment: yes, I know that is a good advise, however, since I'm just rewriting the code in other language, everything should be the same, nothing new. Plus contacting that company and getting a response from them would take a lil longer and wanted to avoid that until the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespace prefix doesn't need to be exactly the same but namespace should be. I can see the namespace of AgencyID and AgentID is not the same in both responses you have shared. If the elements and namespaces are same but namespace prefix is different it will still be a valid response. For further confirmation, you can always validate your new response with the WSDL you have shared with the third party to make sure it works perfectly at their end.

Comment: from where does the code/response get the prefix? like for example: <env:Header/> instead of <s:Header />, or <java:AgencyID instead of <a:AgencyID  ?

Comment: The underlying marshaller decides which prefix to assign to a namespace. For instance, env is assigned to the namespace xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" therefore all the elements under this namespace will be assigned env prefix like <env:Header> <env:Body> etc. You are good as long as namespace is same. Matching the prefixes will simply be a waste of time IMO

Comment: Excellent! thanks for the info. I've been working with WebServices for a coouple years but didn't have a clear idea of how prefixes work. thanks again!